# open specific chrome profile using playwright python

Tags: python, chromium, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to open a specific chrome profile using playwright python using the following code

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    # browser = p.chromium.launch(headless= False, slow_mo= 100000)
    dir_path = r"C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 7"
    print("path :", dir_path)
    browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(channel="chrome", slow_mo= 100000, user_data_dir= dir_path, headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.example.com/login")
```

but it only opens profile 1. I also want to make the automation undetectable if possible.